# Fuzzy sorting of intervals using quicksort

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Problem 7-6 of *Introduction to Algorithms* asks the following:

Consider a sorting problem in which we do not know the numbers exactly.  Instead, for each number, we know an interval on the real line to which it belongs.  That is, we are given *n* closed intervals of the form [*a_i*, *b_i*], where a_i <= b_i.  We wish to ***fuzzy-sort*** these intervals.  (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, & Stein, 2009, p. 189)

Demaine and Goldwasser (2004) clarify that "no interval contains any other interval," or that "if a_i <= a_j, then b_i, b_j."

I have implemented the pseudocode from Lanman (2006).  Although I think I am very close, the functions do not return a correct result on my test input.  My code follows:

```
def sort_fuzzy(intervals, p, s):
    """
    Given a list whose elements are 2-tuples that represent inclusive intervals,
    sort it in place by partitioning it.  Assume no interval completely contains
    any other interval.
    :param  list intervals: An unsorted list of 2-tuples that represent a \
                            closed interval in which a fuzzy value lies.
    :param  int p:          Starting index of the region to sort.
    :param  int s:          Ending index of the region to sort.
    """

    if p < s:
        x = find_intersection(intervals, p, s)
        r = partition_fuzzy_right(intervals, p, s, x)
        q = partition_fuzzy_left_middle(intervals, p, r, x)
        sort_fuzzy(intervals, p, q - 1)
        sort_fuzzy(intervals, r + 1, s)

def partition_fuzzy_right(intervals, p, s, x):
    """
    Given a list whose elements are 2-tuples that represent inclusive intervals,
    partition it into three regions: p to r - 1, r, and r + 1 to s.
    :param  list intervals: An unsorted list of 2-tuples that represent a \
                            closed interval in which a fuzzy value lies.
    :param  int p:          Starting index of the region to sort.
    :param  int s:          Ending index of the region to sort.
    :param  tuple x:        Intersection of intervals.
    """

    i = p - 1
    for j in range(p, s):
        if intervals[j][0] <= x[0]:
            i += 1
            intervals[i], intervals[j] = intervals[j], intervals[i]

    intervals[i + 1], intervals[s] = intervals[s], intervals[i + 1]

    return i + 1

def partition_fuzzy_left_middle(intervals, p, r, x):
    """
    Given a list whose elements are 2-tuples that represent inclusive intervals,
    partition it into four regions: p to q - 1. q, q + 1 to r, and r + 1 to s.
    :param  list intervals: An unsorted list of 2-tuples that represent a \
                            closed interval in which a fuzzy value lies.
    :param  int p:          Starting index of the region to sort.
    :param  int s:          Ending index of the region to sort.
    :param  tuple x:        Intersection of intervals.
    """

    i = p - 1
    for j in range(p, r):
        if intervals[j][1] < x[1]:
            i += 1
            intervals[i], intervals[j] = intervals[j], intervals[i]

    intervals[i + 1], intervals[r] = intervals[r], intervals[i + 1]

    return i + 1

def find_intersection(intervals, p, s):
    """
    Given a list whose elements are 2-tuples that represent inclusive intervals,
    return the intersection of a pivot interval and the 2-tuples if one exists.
    Otherwise, just return the pivot interval.
    :param  list intervals: An unsorted list of 2-tuples that represent a \
                            closed interval in which a fuzzy value lies.
    :param  int p:          Starting index of the region to sort.
    :param  int s:          Ending index of the region to sort.
    """

    x = intervals[s]

    for i in range(p, s):
        if intervals[i][0] <= x[1] and intervals[i][1] >= x[0]:
            if intervals[i][0] > x[0]:
                x = (intervals[i][0], x[1])
            if intervals[i][1] < x[1]:
                x = (x[0], intervals[i][1])

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list = [(13, 20), (19, 21), (9, 11), (5, 7), (12, 16), (8, 10), (7, 9), (4, 6), (20, 24), (2, 2), (6, 8), (11, 15)]
    print(list)
    sort_fuzzy(list, 0, len(list) - 1)
    print(list)
```

Any helps and hints would be very much appreciated.  I've been working on this for days.

UPDATE: A more straightforward implementation of the pseudocode in Lanman (2006), that is, splitting the input array of tuples into an A and a B array and adapting from there, did not help.  I got the same result.

References:

Cormen, T. H., Leiserson, C. E., Rivest, R. L., & Stein, C. (2009). *Introduction to Algorithms* (3rd ed.) [ProQuest Ebook Central version]. Retrieved from https://ebookcentral.proquest.com

Demaine, E., & Goldwasser, S. (2004, February 24). Problem Set 2 [Class handout]. Retrieved from https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/ps2-sol.pdf

Lanman, D. R. (2006, March 13). CS 157: Assignment 3 [Class handout]. Retrieved from http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~dlanman/courses/cs157/HW3.pdf

Comment: you can take help from here [code reference](https://github.com/Frederick-S/Introduction-to-Algorithms-Code/blob/cca8aa46bbfb8f73c6ef1f7301ce574d5d4f64d8/src/chapter_7/fuzzy_sorting_of_intervals.py)

Comment: Why not just sort the left edges?

Comment: btw using built-ins as object names (like `list` in your example) will end up in problems

Comment: Without reading all those papers, what exactly is the idea behind fuzzy sorting? Why not just sort by left or right edge or midpoints? Do you want a search that minimizes swaps?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yes, I found that out creating python packages.  In my tests, I change the variable name, but I haven't started doing that in my main functions yet.  It's a Swift habit to use very explicit names.

Comment: @tobias_k  It improves the expected running time.  According to Cormen et al. (2009), it runs at O(n log n) like it would for normal quicksort ... sorting by edges or a midpoint.  However, when all the intervals overlap, it runs in O(n).  You can speed up quicksort by adding an extra partition for elements equal to the pivot value.  Likewise, here you are treating the overlapping elements as equal to the pivot.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Read my comment to Tobias.

Comment: @prashantrana  Using the following input: `[[13, 20], [19, 21], [9, 11], [5, 7], [12, 16], [8, 10], [7, 9], [4, 6], [20, 24], [2, 2], [6, 8], [11, 15]]`, I get the following output: `[[2, 2], [5, 7], [6, 8], [4, 6], [8, 10], [7, 9], [11, 15], [9, 11], [12, 16], [19, 21], [13, 20], [20, 24]]`.  Is there something wrong with my input?  No interval completely contains any other interval as far as I have noticed, although I've made such mistakes before posting here.  Do you see anything else?

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with that output, and why, and what output would you have expected?

Comment: @michaelgill1969 try to use the [test case](https://github.com/Frederick-S/Introduction-to-Algorithms-Code/blob/cca8aa46bbfb8f73c6ef1f7301ce574d5d4f64d8/tests/chapter_7/fuzzy_sorting_of_intervals_test.py) written by him, i haven't solved this problem yet , if your code run on this test case then , you are good with this solution

Comment: @tobias_k `2 | 2 ∈ [2, 2] <= 5 | 5 ∈ [5, 7] <= 6 | 6 ∈ [6, 8] <= 6 | 6 ∈ [4, 6] <= 8 | 8 ∈ [8, 10] <= 8 | 8 ∈ [7, 9] <= 11 | 11 ∈ [11, 15] <= 11 | 11 ∈ [9, 11] <= 12 | 12 ∈ [12, 16] <= 19 | 19 ∈ [19, 21] <= 19 | 19 ∈ [13, 20] <= 20 | 20 ∈ [20, 24]`  I think I get it now, thanks!  You know, I think I had a correct solution to this problem long before even looking up Lanman's pseudocode.  Shall I write up an answer or would you like to get the credit you are well due?

Comment: @michaelgill1969 The only thing I did was not understanding what the code is supposed to do. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @tobias_k pointed out, my problem was not understanding the question or what a correct solution looks like.  Regarding a correct solution, Cormen et al. (2009) stated, "We wish to fuzzy-sort these intervals, i.e., to produce a permutation  of the intervals such that for j = 1, 2, ..., n, there exist c_j ∈ [a_i_j, b_i_j] satisfying c_1 <= c_2 <= ... <= c_n."

So, for the input `[(13, 20), (19, 21), (9, 11), (5, 7), (12, 16), (8, 10), (7, 9), (4, 6), (20, 24), (2, 2), (6, 8), (11, 15)]`, my code outputs `[(2, 2), (4, 6), (6, 8), (7, 9), (5, 7), (8, 10), (9, 11), (11, 15), (13, 20), (12, 16), (19, 21), (20, 24)]`, which ***is*** a correct solution.

You see, just as Cormen et al. (2009) wrote, if *any* number in an interval is greater than or equal to *any* number in an interval preceding it, it may correctly follow that preceding interval.  In other words, consider the following:

```
2 | 2 ∈ [2, 2] <= 4 | 4 ∈ [4, 6] <= 6 | 6 ∈ [6, 8] <= 7 | 7 ∈ [7, 9] <= 7 | 7 ∈ [5, 7] 8 | 8 ∈ <= [8, 10] <= 9 | 9 ∈ [9, 11] <= 11 | 11 ∈ [11, 15] <= 13 | 13 ∈ [13, 20] <= 13 | 13 ∈ [12, 16] <= 19 | 19 ∈ [19, 21] <= 20 | 20 ∈ [20, 24]
```

It is ***not*** necessary that the left edges be sorted in increasing order, but only that the intervals overlap in some fuzzily increasing order.  See page four of Lanman (2006) and really understand what a correct fuzzy-sort is before solving the problem.

References:

Cormen, T. H., Leiserson, C. E., Rivest, R. L., & Stein, C. (2009). *Introduction to Algorithms* (3rd ed.) [ProQuest Ebook Central version]. Retrieved from https://ebookcentral.proquest.com

Lanman, D. R. (2006, March 13). CS 157: Assignment 3 [Class handout]. Retrieved from http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~dlanman/courses/cs157/HW3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since the intervals don't contain each other, you could either sort by left edge, middle or right edge and you will get the same exact answer.

If you want to make the sorting fuzzy, you could sample the interval (assuming uniform or whatever distribution you want and sort on the sampled values.

Comment: Yes, you can choose some element of the interval and you will get the same answer, but it will run slower on some inputs.  As I mentioned above, when all intervals intersect, the running time can improve to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but here's my solution. It's written in C too, but it should convey the idea well.

```
// struct representing an interval
typedef struct interval interval;
struct interval{
    double first;
    double second;
};

// fuzzy-sort the interval [start, end)
void fuzzy_sort(size_t start, size_t end, interval arr[])
{
    size_t x = start;       // head of the < partition + 1
    size_t y = start + 1;   // head of the = partition + 1
    size_t z = end;         // bottom of the > partition

    if(y >= z)
        return;
    // common overlap interval of equal
    // elements starting
    // with arr[start] as pivot
    double p1 = arr[start].first, p2 = arr[start].second;

    while(y < z){
        if(arr[y].second < p1){
            interval hold = arr[y];
            arr[y] = arr[x];
            arr[x] = hold;
            ++x, ++y;
        }
        else if(arr[y].first > p2){
            interval hold = arr[y];
            arr[y ] = arr[z - 1];
            arr[z - 1] = hold;
            --z;
        }
        else{
            // max
            p1 = p1 < arr[y].first ? arr[y].first : p1;
            // min
            p2 = p2 > arr[y].second ? arr[y].second : p2;
            ++y;
        }
    }
    fuzzy_sort(start, x, arr);
    fuzzy_sort(z, end, arr);
}

// return 1 if arr is fuzzy-sorted, else 0
int is_fuzzy_sorted(size_t n, interval arr[])
{
    double last = arr[0].first;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        if(last > arr[i].second)
            return 0;
        last = last < arr[i].first ? arr[i].first : last;
    }
    return 1;
        
}
```

Mid-execution, the array might look somthing like this

[-less-->|-equals-->|<----unpartitioned---->|<---greater--]

The idea is to partition the array into three regions: those with a mutual overlap interval along with the pivot, those completely less than this interval, and those completely greater than it. The ones with a mutual overlap interval(middle partition) may appear in any order, so the algorithm recursively sorts only the left and right partitions.
Also, if there's a common interval, the algorithm makes exactly one pass through the array, as stated in the original question in Cormen et al. (2022).

When run with your input, the code outputs:
{(2, 2), (4, 6), (7, 9), (5, 7), (6, 8), (8, 10), (11, 15), (9, 11), (12, 16), (13, 20), (19, 21), (20, 24)}
which also is a correct answer.

I only just developed it this morning, and can roughly explain why it works, but no mathematical rigour. Please, feel free to criticize.